# Google Maps API without API Key (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps, api-key

Is that possible to use Google Maps API without API Key?

Answer (score 1):

For you to use any **Google Maps APIs**, you need to have an **API key** from a project which is linked to a valid billing account. The APIs won't work if you won't include your API key in your request. Checkout this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) for more information.

If you don't want to pay for a map display, an alternative you can do is use [Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) **Basic mode** which enables you to display a map in a website for free though you still need to have an API key to be able to use Maps Embed API.

Another alternative is by using [Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) where in you can launch Google Maps, perfom searches, get directions and navigation, and display map views and panoramic images on any platform without using an API key.

Just an additional note, while you are in the development stage, please be mindful of [Google Maps Platform Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/) especially in **Section 3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services**.